# How to repeat that animation in the PaperJS?

Tags: paperjs

I found [this interesting animation](https://twitter.com/MattDzugan/status/1367613059330699267) and wonder if it's possible to repeat it in the PaperJS? It seems like it could be made of a group of circles, rotated around another circle.

But the problem is - when these objects are in a group I can't use sendToBack() per each, it's not going to work. Here is the [Sketch example](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#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), that doesn't work.

*P.S. Here is a [simplified version](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#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) of how it could be achieved, but it works only for 1 element, and only for animation along one axis.*

Comment: you don't need to group the objects, just apply them the same transformation (with the proper delay).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you still want to have your object grouped, a basic solution could be to have 2 groups: one below and one above the circle and toggle items visibility.
Just to demonstrate the idea, this [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#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) extends your code in this way.
I think that the way you currently decide if the item should be below or above can be improved though for a better result (you could try to detect intersection between the item and the circle rather than only checking the position).